# Partition hard drive on ubuntu phone

Tags: partitioning

I currently have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus (the same phone used in the Ubuntu phone video) and I would like to know if there is any way to partition the hard drive so I can still run Android as well as Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try Ubuntu but not lose your Android, you can use a dual-boot setup. There is a working solution for Ubuntu 13.04 on the [XDA mobile developer forum.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011403) See also bug [1078391](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1078391).